# Doctrine Dbal: How to set collation? (in Symfony2)

Tags: character-encoding, doctrine, collation, symfony

I'm used to creating the PDO object with something like this in the 4th parameter (driver options):

```
array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES {$this->charset} COLLATE {$this->collation}")
```

How can I tell symfony 2 to do this? In the configuration file I can only see a 'charset' option.

I also need to create all the tables with a specific collation: utf8_unicode_ci

What can I do to have all the tables created through the command line be created with that collation instead of latin1?

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same problem. It seems that has to do with DBAL configuration. I have found in the PDO documentation the following under the PDO_MYSQL DSN — Connecting to MySQL databases:

charset Currently ignored.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to apply the collation manually at the database level.  Then all tables created in Symfony2 with the schema update command will have the correct collation.

I also added this line to my Sf2 doctrine: dbal configuration in the config.yml:

```
    charset: utf8
```