# Illegal mix of collations in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have this piece of code which permits me to search all the database.

The question is i get this error:

```
llegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

My query looks something like this:

```
$sql = "select * from hostess where hostess_id like '%$term%' or.....
```

When i search for russian words.
How can i prevent doing it like that? 
Thanks.

Comment: Just a wild guess but, is your table collation set to latin1_swedish_ci, but your connection to the server is set to UTF?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, @Lion, i have given a part of my query...
and Ignas well, the table fields are a mix of latin1_swedish_ci and utf8_bin

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Illegal mix of collations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247120/mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations)