# MySQL Union illegal mix of collations

Tags: php, mysql, sql, collate

I have the following in my PHP query:

```
SELECT tags.tag, theValues.* 
FROM ch09.tbl_tags tags 
RIGHT JOIN ((SELECT 'dog' as 'Vals')
UNION (SELECT 'cat' as 'Vals')) theValues on tags.tag = theValues.Vals
```

After the "RIGHT JOIN" everything within the brackets are created on the fly from user input.

It worked fine in MySQL 4, but I just had a new computer and installed 5.5, imported the SQL dump as `UTF-8`. But I get:

> "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='"

There's probably a better way to construct my query, all I need is everything the user inputs in one column as "`Vals`" and if there's a matching tag in `tbl_tags.tag` then it should be there in a column called "tag" else the tag column is blank.

I have tried using Collate: http://www.answermysearches.com/mysql-fixing-illegal-mix-of-collations-message/352/, but I simply cannot get it to work.

So I need to either construct a better query or use the collate function somehow, but how?

Thanks in advance.

Craig

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see the following question:  [MySQL Encoding Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247120/mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations?rq=1)

I think the problem actually deals with the encoding of the Column and SQL text.  To get around this, try using the [CONVERT(aaa USING bbb)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//cast-functions.html#function_convert) function as follows in your WHERE clause:

```
SELECT tags.tag, theValues.* 
  FROM ch09.tbl_tags tags 
 RIGHT JOIN ((SELECT 'dog' as 'Vals')
       UNION (SELECT 'cat' as 'Vals')) theValues
   ON CONVERT(tags.tag USING utf8) = theValues.Vals
```

Alternatively, change your table's column encoding to be UTF8.

Hope this helps,

john...

Comment: Note that `ON tags.tag = theValues.Vals COLLATE utf8_general_ci` should work as well.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot John !