# General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql

This error shows up whenever I use different characters in Select query like このファイルをテス and use it on sql..

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=' (SQL: select * from `folders` where `folder_name` = このファイルをテスト)

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Illegal mix of collations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247120/mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations)

Answer (score 0):

what is type of column 'folde_name' ?
if it's varchar or nvarchar have to used cot char like this

folder_name ='you text'

if use that and have this exception, please check the collation of db. that must be support your languege.

you can change the collation of column and table, but can not change the database collation.