# Error Number: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Tags: mysql, utf-8, collation

Table Name: xyz
    Type: InnoDB
    Collation:latin1_swedish_ci

**Fields**:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Field        | Type        | Collation         | Extra        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            id           | int         |                   | Primary Key  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
            name         | varchar     | latin1_swedish_ci |              |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is my database table. And When I am trying to insert a value for name something like this

```
If T₀, T₁, T₂ . . . . . . . Tn represent the terms in the expansion of (x + a)n, then (T₀ - T₂ + T₄ - . . )2 + (T₁ - T₃ + T₅ - . . )2
```

I get the following error:

```
Error Number: 1267Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

I did a quick research & found many S.O questions and articles providing solutions but none of them worked for me.

My Reference: [Visit](http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations/)

I tried changing the collation of the table using a query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE xyz CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

But the error remained still.

I also tried using `utf8_unicode_ci` but that also didn't work.

Reasons? Solutions? Gracias.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Illegal mix of collations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247120/mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @vhu for marking this as duplicate.

Answer Courtesy: @Marvin W

I modified my table and that fixed my problem.

```
ALTER TABLE xyz CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: mysql v8.0.18 shows warning about utf8 being alias to a deprecated UTF8MB4, so giving the new charset works well: `ALTER TABLE xyz CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET UTF8MB4;`